# Can't get the "First Name" and "Last Name" textfields adjacent

Tags: html, css, forms, web

1. Below, I've a web form which has all the text-fields stacked vertical upon each other, and I want the FirstName and LastName text-field inputs adjacent to each other.
2. Also, I can't get to animate the same hovering effects on these two fields, as that in the last two input text-fields.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster Two">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <title>FLUX - A Cloud Based Service</title>
</head>

<body>

    <hgroup>
        <h1>Flux</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x"></i>
        <h2>A Cloud Based Service</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <form action="index.html">

        <div class="section-1">
            <div>
                <!--  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>  -->
                <input type="text" class="text" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'First Name';}" id="active">
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="text" class="text" value="Last Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'Last Name';}" id="active">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-2">
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i> -->
            <input type="text" class="text" value="user@email.com" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'user@email.com';}">

            <!--    <i class="fa fa-key fa-2x"></i>  -->
            <input type="password" class="text" value="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'password';}">
        </div>
        <h3>By creating an account, you agree to our <span class="term"><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></span></h3>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </div>
        <h3 id="second-h3">Already a member? Click <a href="#">Here</a></h3>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/retina.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
    background-image: url(../images/VBKHtidQKL.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
hgroup {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Lobster Two;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-stretch: extra-expanded;
}
form {
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 1366px;
    max-height: 768px;
}
h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
#second-h3 {
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
.section-1 input[type="text"] {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    color: #666666;
    width: 87%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Raleway;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 8px solid #fff;
}
.section-2 input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    padding: 16px;
    width: 92%;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    color: #666666;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Raleway;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 8px solid #fff;
    float: left;
}
.section-1 input[type="text"]:hover, .section-2 input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover, #active {
    color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    border-left: 8px solid rgb(64, 164, 111);
}
.submit {
    padding: 6px 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 18px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-family: Raleway;
    background: rgb(64, 164, 111);
    border: 1px solid rgb(64, 164, 111);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.submit[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: rgb(7, 121, 61);
    border: 1px solid rgb(7, 121, 61);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to note that ids must be unique. I noticed at least a couple instances where you used the same id. I changed them to become classes.

The div elements which house your inputs are by default block level elements. This means they are supposed to take up the full width of the page. To change this, we can change the display options for these types of elements. `inline-block` will allow two divs to be adjacent to eachother

```css
#first, #second {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<hgroup>
        <h1>Flux</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x"></i>
        <h2>A Cloud Based Service</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <form action="index.html">

        <div class="section-1">
            <div id="first">
                <!--  <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>  -->
                <input type="text" class="text" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'First Name';}" class="active">
            </div>

            <div id="second">
                <input type="text" class="text" value="Last Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'Last Name';}" class="active">
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-2">
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i> -->
            <input type="text" class="text" value="user@email.com" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'user@email.com';}">

            <!--    <i class="fa fa-key fa-2x"></i>  -->
            <input type="password" class="text" value="password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'password';}">
        </div>
        <h3>By creating an account, you agree to our <span class="term"><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></span></h3>

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </div>
        <h3 id="second-h3">Already a member? Click <a href="#">Here</a></h3>

    </form>
```